# Mysql хранение значений атрибутов в связанной таблице

Tags: mysql

столкнулся с такой проблемой при проектировки бд.
имеется таблица элементов, и таблица с атрибутами[id,name]
связь между ними многие ко многим через таблицу связей [id, el_id, atr_id],
но необходимо еще хранить и значения для атрибутов так как таблица атрибутов это просто список атрибутов, а наличие атрибутов у элемента обуславливается таблицей связи (связь есть, значит и атрибут есть)

Можно ли хранить значение атрибутов в таблице связей, (и как оптимально потом их подгружать) или же все-таки нужно выстроить другую схему c 3 таблицей например:

elem_table[id, name, ...] -> Таблица связей[elem_id, atr_elem_id] <-atr_elem_table[id, atr_id, value] <-atr_table[id,name]

Comment: кажется, вам виднее должно быть, подходит вариант хранения вместе со связью или нет. В целом это типично, что атрибуты связи хранятся здесь же.

Comment: *имеется таблица элементов, и таблица с атрибутами[id,name]* Не используйте слово "атрибут" в значении, отличающемся от  того значения, которое используется в теории реляционных БД. Лучше используйте термин "свойство". *Можно ли хранить значение атрибутов в таблице связей* Зависит от того, является ли значение атрибутом свойства или атрибутом связи. В первом случае значения хранятся в таблице свойств, во втором - в связующей таблице.

Comment: Не можно, а нужно хранить значение атрибута именно в таблице связей. Оптимально подгружать - ни как, данная структура предназначена для обеспечения непротиворечивости данных, выборка всех значений атрибутов к конкретному объекту будет затратной операцией. Для быстрой выборки рекомендуется либо отдельно кешировать эти данные, либо при изменении таблицы связей триггерами складывать все значения в виде какого нибудь json к самому элементу, либо в таблице элементов либо в отдельной со связью с элементов один к одному.

Comment: P.S. поле id в таблице связей не нужно, первичный ключом стоит сделать пару elem_id, atr_elem_id

Comment: @Mike фреймворки любят автоинкеремент добавлять в таблицу отношений всегда.